# PHP function return. Nested functions

Tags: php, wordpress, function, return, shortcode

I know there's Wordpress StackExchange, but that's more PHP related question.

I'm writing my own shortcode for Wordpress it looks like:

```
function myShortcode_shortcode() {

    return 'something';

}
```

This shortcode displays simple string "something".

The problem is I want to display an image from template directory:

```
 <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/images/myImage.jpg" alt="" />
```

And I don't know how?

When I do:

```
return '<img src="'. bloginfo('template_directory') .'/images/myImage.jpg" alt="" />';
```

Script is echoing template directory instead of image.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the "shortcode" part have to do with the "template directory" part?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the [`bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) function is an output function (intended for templates). You need [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) rather.

Answer (score 0):

You probly need to place `<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/images/myImage.jpg" alt="" />` in his own variable like

```
function shortcode(){ 
$shortcode = "<img src='". bloginfo('template_directory') ."/images/myImage.jpg' alt="" />"
return $shortcode;
}
```

Hope this helps